# OpenVPN - unable to ping LAN

Tags: debian, openvpn

All,

I have an OpenVPN server setup in our Production environment with one client OpenVPN server connected to it. I am setting up a second client connected to the same VPN server. I believe my configuration is correct because I the tunnel came up, and I am able to ping both sides of the tunnel from each of the Client and Server. I have a PC on each side of the tunnel that need the ability to communicate.

NetworkA - 172.21.0.0/16
NetworkB - 192.168.1.0/24

PC-A (172.21.0.101) is behind the OpenVPN Server (172.21.7.13) and can ping the OpenVPN Server and the OpenVPN client. It can successfully ping 192.168.1.29 (OpenVPN client)

PC-B (192.168.1.240) is behind OpenVPN Client, and it can ping the OpenVPN client (192.168.1.29). PC-B cannot ping the OpenVPN Server or PC-A.

Ideally I need these machines to be able to talk, but I seem to be missing something.

Below is the Route Print from PC-A:

```
    IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.21.0.1     172.21.0.101    266
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      172.21.7.13     172.21.0.101     11
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.21.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      172.21.0.101    266
     172.21.0.101  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.21.0.101    266
   172.21.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.21.0.101    266
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      172.21.7.13     172.21.0.101     11
    192.168.1.240  255.255.255.255      172.21.7.13     172.21.0.101     11
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.21.0.101    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.21.0.101    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      172.21.7.13       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.21.0.1  Default 
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      172.21.7.13       1
===========================================================================
```

Below is the Route Print from PC-B:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  169.254.169.123  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     50
  169.254.169.249  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     50
  169.254.169.250  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     50
  169.254.169.251  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     50
  169.254.169.253  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     50
  169.254.169.254  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.240     50
       172.21.0.0      255.255.0.0     192.168.1.29    192.168.1.240     26
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.240    281
    192.168.1.240  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.240    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.240    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.240    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.240    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
  169.254.169.254  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      25
  169.254.169.250  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      25
  169.254.169.251  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      25
  169.254.169.249  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      25
  169.254.169.123  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      25
  169.254.169.253  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      25
       172.21.0.0      255.255.0.0     192.168.1.29       1
===========================================================================
```

I have the firewalls on both remote PC's turned off at this time. PC-B is an EC2 instance in AWS, but I have allowed ICMP from any location at this time. I am kind of confused to why this would not be working, so any advice is much appreciated.

Please let me know if anymore information is required here.

Thanks

Comment: What's the address of the network used by the OpenVPN's tunnel? I reckon it's 10/8, but if yes, PC-B lacks routing entry for this network, and so it should not be able to talk to the OpenVPN server.

Comment: The VPN tunnel address is 172.17.0.0/24

Comment: 10.0.0.0/8 is the address to a secondary client OpenVPN we have set up which I do not have these issues on.

Comment: 172.17.0.0/24 is not listed in the routing table of both PCs, which I find weird. But OK. The next question is whether you have IPv4 forwarding enabled on the OpenVPN client? Just in case, have you read <https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans>?